# Genymotion didn't get an ip address from virtual box

Tags: android, emulation, genymotion

I've installed genymotion about 2 days ago and I've been facing the same problem every time I tried to start a device.

After I downloaded a device in genymotion (Nexus S - 4.2.2 - API 17 - 480*800) I launched it.
Then after a box poped up telling me I have to wait, I got this error:

> The virtual terminal genymotion didn't get an ip address. For an
>   unknown reason the virtualbox's dhcp servor didn't assign an ip adress
>   to the virtual terminal. Please launch virtualbox to find a solution
>   to this problem

I can't figure out how to solve this problem. 
I looked up on many websites but it seems as if I'm the only one to get this error.

I'm on Windows XP-SP3.
My graphic card is a radeon HD 3600 driver up to date.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you open VirtualBox and check the config of your device?

Comment: I did and everything seems normal. The dhcp server is enabled. In network tab I checked "Enable network adapter" and set to "host-only adapter". Actually I didn't change anything after I've installed it.

Comment: You should push a mail to support@genymotion.com. They will be able to digg a little bit more on your problem.

Comment: Same error, did you finally manage to find the issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Try downgrading to Virtual Box 4.2.18, if you are using 4.3.X.**

I had a similar situation to yours.

I was using Genymotion 1.3.0 on Win7, with latest Virtual Box 4.3.2. Genymotion broke down after a computer shutdown, and never worked again.

I kinda stumbled onto this solution. After downgrading, Genymotion survived one shutdown now.

Answer (score 0):

All Android VMs used to work for me under Genymotion 2.0.0. with default RAM and CPU settings and VirtualBox 4.3.2 (on ubuntu 13.10). Upgrading to 2.0.1 made them stop working and give the error you mentioned.

I tried various fixes as I described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20018833/2527118, but in summary what fixed my problem was to delete VM and recreate it (same source and settings) in GenyMotion. You might want to try the other fixes (less destructive) before doing that.

Andrei

Answer (score 0):

I try to solve this for 6 days and in the end, I realized I needed to uninstall then re install virtual box so I can get their default settings then change my network settings as explained better in this link. It explains in depth how the ip address works with the virtual machine, and how the chances of it trying to use a static ip address are very likely.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/232876/how-to-let-a-virtualbox-guest-running-windows-access-the-internet

let your network settings be handled by themselves if you've tried everything, maybe this will allow your VM to use its own IP address and stop trying to use your Physical devices IP address.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old. But my answer is just for someone who google this issue and hopefully it may help them since I also stuck on it for a long time and fix it fortunately.

This is my way to fix the problem:

1. First of all, I had configured all the settings what the people said on the internet like the following link: [Not able to start Genymotion device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641423/not-able-to-start-genymotion-device)
2. I found that it's still failed to run the VM on GenyMotion.
3. So I tried to **remove all the existing Host-only Network** like vboxnet0 or vboxnet1(According to the official website of GenyMotion, it said that it will regenerate a new one when there is no any vboxnet)
4. Finally, I tried to restart the VM on　GenyMotion, suddenly I run it successfully without any errors message

**Notes:** I disabled the adaptor 2, 3 and 4 before I was gonna tried the above actions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem with the IP error, too. As I have a real Samsung Galaxy S2, I downloaded the vitual version 2.3.7 Api 10 in Genimotion. All IP settings were correct, the sequence of starting the programms didn`t matter. The IP error reoccured :( .
Finaly, I tried to use another virtual device: Custom Tablet 5.1.0 API 22. It loaded and worked, but very slow. WhatsApp got stuck on the installation process :( . As this article on Heisse.de recomended to use the Nexus S 4.1.1 for WhatsApp, I tried this third vitual device and everything worked fine :) !
http://www.heise.de/download/special-whatsapp-auf-pc-mac-und-linux-nutzen-152241.html?hg=1&hgi=3&hgf=false

Answer (score 0):

As other have said, you have to install Virtual Box. In my case (using Ubuntu 16.04), I had to enable the 'virtualization' in Bios. Once that was setup, I was able to set the 'OS' to use 'Ubuntu 64bit' in 'settings/general' tab.

[image]

Other possible solutions include, configuring Virtual Box further, including reducing the RAM usage (in settings), in 'Network' tab in settings, under 'advanced' options, disabling the 'cable connected' option & setting 'Promiscuous mode' to 'allow all'.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IN case a Genymotion device cannot obtain an IP address any more, you might want to check the configuration in the VM-Ware settings: I got this fixed by removing the "promiscous mode" from the network adapter 1 settings - see screenshot.
[The promiscous setting may lead to difficulties in obtaining an IP address in the genymotion simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptJdu.png)