# Not able to start Genymotion device

Tags: android, genymotion

I am getting an error when I try to start Genymotion. It says

> The Genymotion Virtual device could not obtain an IP address.For an
>   unknown reason, VirtualBox DHCP has not assigned an IP address to
>   virtual device. Run the VirtualBox software to check for issues

Can someone please tell me how to start it?

Comment: For me simply trying again worked.
I got the error the first time but it worked the second time.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I had this same issue and here are the specific configuration that I needed to get this to work.

First, go to the VirtualBox preferences -> Network.

[image]

[image]

[image]

For the "Host-only Networks" tab, focus on the vboxnet0.

[image]

Click the icon on the left that looks like a screwdriver.
For the Adapter tab, fill in the IPv4 Network Address as 192.168.56.1
Fill in the IPv4 Network Mask as 255.255.255.0

[image]

For the DHCP Server tab, select the check box for Enable Server to enable the server
Fill in the Server Address as 192.168.56.100
Fill in the Server Mask as 255.255.255.0
Fill in the Lower Address Bound as 192.168.56.101
Fill in the Upper Address Bound as 192.168.56.254

[image]

The DHCP server part is what was not correct for me and it fixed my problem.

Comment: Worked for me on OS X 10.9

Comment: This didn't work for me on Windows 8.1. My settings were correct. In the end I disabled Hyper-V and suddenly it worked (it's also faster if you disable Hyper-V). Too bad I actually need Hyper-V for my Windows Phone Emulator. Currently solved that by making a double boot, one with and one without Hyper-V. Still kinda sucks that I have to restart my computer. Thought this might be useful in case the above fix didn't work.

Comment: The above fix doesn't work for me, and also my Windows 8.1 computer does not have a Hyper-V feature

Comment: Thanks to @LanderV I have given a step-by-step instruction how to do this in [this answer on this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641423/not-able-to-start-genymotion-device/33257560#answer-33257560).

Answer (score 26):

This worked for me..

**Open Virtual Box and select your mobile VM. Right click->Settings**

[image]

**Change Promiscuous mode to Allow VMS and click ok**
[image]

Comment: i coudn't find tabs in installed virtual box like last screenshot

Comment: Unfortunatelly did not help :/

Comment: It works only after we select current OS in settings. Make sure if it is 64 bti then 64 bit is selected. If only 32 bit is displayed, enable virtualization in BIOS.

Answer (score 17):

In virtualbox, go to the settings / network, and remove all `host only` networks. Make sure to go to the global settings of virtualbox, not the settings of your specific VM.

The settings screen should look like this:

[image]

Then restart your emulator in Genymotion.

Answer (score 11):

I think you should configure your VirtualBox network adapter:

> The adapter's IP address has to be in the same network
>   (192.168.56.0/24 by default) as DHCP server's IP address and DHCP's IP
>   address bounds. If all those addresses are not in the same network,
>   then your Genymotion virtual device might not be able to start.

https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/faq/#collapse-blank

Or check log files to get a clue:

> For each platform, the log files are stored here:
>     Windows Vista/7/8: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Genymobile
>     Windows XP: C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Local settings\Application Data\Genymobile
>     Linux: /home/USER/.Genymobile
>     Mac: /Users/USER/.Genymobile

https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/faq/#collapse-logs

Comment: Deleting the Host-only network solved the issue. It recreated another one when I started my virtual device.

Comment: @Sammys where to delete

Comment: links unactive, please fix it

Answer (score 7):

**If you are using a Windows PC, check this first (this list looks quite long, but the first three bullets will let you know if Hyper-V could be your problem, and the next five bullets will tell you if this answer will solve your problem - just a few moments!):**

- Open a good old-fashioned command prompt (not a PowerShell) with admin privileges and type:

  `bcdedit`

  <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Take a look for an item in the list called: `hypervisorlaunchtype`.
- If `hypervisorlaunchtype` isn't in the list, or is `Off`, exit this answer and take a look at one of the other answers on this page.
- If `hypervisorlaunchtype` is in the list and is set to `Auto`, Hyper-V is installed and is enabled.
- Disable `hypervisorlaunchtype` by typing

  `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`

  <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Reboot
- Try to start your Genymotion device again.
- If it still fails enable `hypervisorlaunchtype` by typing into an admin command prompt:

  `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype Auto`

  <kbd>Enter</kbd>

  - Reboot
  - Exit this answer and take a look at one of the other answers on this page.
- Otherwise, if your Genymotion device now starts, you have a choice:

  - If you don't need Hyper-V remove it by un-checking it in `Turn Windows Features On or Off` and exit this question.
  - If you do need Hyper-V, allow easy enabling and disabling as per [Scott Hanselman's blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SwitchEasilyBetweenVirtualBoxAndHyperVWithABCDEditBootEntryInWindows81.aspx), which I will outline in the following bullets:
- You can leave the default as `Off` and then add an item to the boot menu that allows you to switch it on, or vice versa.
- If you are leaving the default as `Off` type the following into the admin command prompt:

  ```
  bcdedit /copy {current} /d "Hyper-V"
  ```

  <kbd>Enter</kbd>

  and you will get a response like this:

  ```
  The entry was successfully copied to {ff-23-113-824e-5c5144ea}.
  ```

  - then type:

    `bcdedit /set {ff-23-113-824e-5c5144ea} hypervisorlaunchtype auto`

    <kbd>Enter</kbd>

  (ensuring you swap the GUID for the one your call to `copy` above gave you)

  - That's it, your done. (In order to switch between the two hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you go for a `Restart` and then select `Other Operating Systems` on the blue screen and then `Hyper-V` on the subsequent screen and your OS will restart with Hyper-V enabled.)
- If you want Hyper-V to be enabled by default type into your admin command prompt:

  ```
  bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype Auto
  ```

  <kbd>Enter</kbd>

  (which will revert the default boot to enabling Hyper-V)
- Then type the following in the admin command prompt:

  ```
  bcdedit /copy {current} /d "No Hyper-V"
  ```

  <kbd>Enter</kbd>

  and you will get a response like this:

  ```
  The entry was successfully copied to {ff-23-113-824e-5c5144ea}.
  ```

  - then type:

    `bcdedit /set {ff-23-113-824e-5c5144ea} hypervisorlaunchtype off`

    <kbd>Enter</kbd>

  (ensuring you swap the GUID for the one your call to `copy` above gave you)

  - That's it, you're done. (As with `off` by default above, in order to switch between the two hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you go for a `Restart` and then select `Other Operating Systems` on the blue screen and `Hyper-V` on the subsequent screen and your OS will restart with Hyper-V enabled.)

---

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641423/not-able-to-start-genymotion-device/21486549#comment-43249430) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641423/not-able-to-start-genymotion-device/21486549#answer-28014938) to the question you are currently reading lead me to the resolution in my case and I am adding this answer to outline simple steps to take before you spend a lot of time on any solution - that comment and answer do get you where this answer will take you, but I have laid it out step-by-step in the hope that you can save time.

Background:

[This article by Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SwitchEasilyBetweenVirtualBoxAndHyperVWithABCDEditBootEntryInWindows81.aspx) gave me the meat of what I have outlined, with [this comment on that blog post by Jonathan Dickinson](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SwitchEasilyBetweenVirtualBoxAndHyperVWithABCDEditBootEntryInWindows81.aspx#c28827cf-9db6-4c55-94c7-a1cd669a24d4) helping with my background understanding and preventing me disappearing down a rabbit hole, but [this article by Derek Gusoff](https://derekgusoff.wordpress.com/2012/09/05/run-hyper-v-and-virtualbox-on-the-same-machine/) fine tuned the steps above.

Comment: This was my issue. After trying all other listed solutions without success I disabled Hyper-V which solved my issue

Answer (score 6):

VMs used to work for me under Genymotion 2.0.0. with default RAM and CPU settings and VirtualBox 4.3.2 (on ubuntu 13.10). Upgrading to 2.0.1 made them stop working and give the error you mentioned.

I tried various fixes as I described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20018833/2527118, but in summary what fixed my problem was to delete VM and recreate it (same source and settings) in GenyMotion. You might want to try the other fixes (less destructive) before doing that.

Andrei

Comment: Thanks! This and the lack of virtual resources tip from Salman fixed mine right up.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I restart the computer and enable the virtualization technology in BIOS. Then start up computer, open `VM Virtual Box`, choose a virtual device, go to `Settings`-`General`-`Basic`-`Version`, choose `ubuntu(64 bit)`, save the settings then start virtual device from genymotion, everything is ok now.

Comment: 64 bit very important. By default it comes with 32.

Comment: When you create an emulator with more than 1GB of RAM or more than 1 Core (CPU)... 
I believe it should have to be x64 to work! I replaced the 32-bit version of P / 64-bit and now worked! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

After trying all of these answers, to no avail, I managed to get it up by first running the device from Vbox, leaving it open, and then running the device from Genymotion... In my case this was the ONLY way after trying several different devices (Samsung S4/S6 etc), network/DHCP settings and modes and so on...

Comment: It's worth noting that I waited to see "IP Management" message from the VBox console before running in Genymotion

Comment: This solution worked for me.. I'm using **Windows 10, VirtualBox 6.0.12 and Genymotion 3.0.2**. For me other solutions did not work. I have enabled already **Enabled Virtualization Technology** in **BIOS** settings

Comment: after struggling all day i found this answer and it did the trick. many thanks

Answer (score 4):

In my case, Global Settings matters.
After I changed my global network setting with DHCP Servers on, I could start my genymotion virtual device.

1. cmd+, or File > Settings
2. Network
3. Host only Network
4. select vboxnet0, click driver icon
5. Check DHCP on

I blogged it. http://okjsp.tistory.com/1165644212 (sorry for korean, but you can see it from images)

Answer (score 4):

I struggled quite a long time fixing this issue. In my case it was a combination of 2 answers that got it to work. Visual studio enabled my Hyper-V. I had to turn it off as suggested by LanderV. After this, I had to delete the Host-only network adapter in Virtualbox like Sammys said.

Comment: Thanks for this; this worked for me and I have given a step-by-step instruction how to do this in [this answer on this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641423/not-able-to-start-genymotion-device/33257560#answer-33257560).

Answer (score 3):

For me it was related to the lack of virtual resources (Ram and CPU). Go to the virtual box, right click on device -> **Setting** and increase the value of each resource.

Comment: Thanks! This and the fix from Andrei's link got my up and running again http://stackoverflow.com/a/20018833/2527118

Answer (score 3):

**Try downgrading to Virtual Box 4.2.18, if you are using 4.3.X.**

I had a similar situation to yours.

I was using Genymotion 1.3.0 on Win7, with latest Virtual Box 4.3.2. Genymotion broke down after a computer shutdown, and never worked again.

I kinda stumbled onto this solution. After downgrading, Genymotion survived one shutdown now.

P.S. Changing network/resources settings in Virtual Box didn't help me, so I'm putting this up and hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

First of All, Make Sure to **Enable Virtualization Technology** under **BIOS** settings.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: Remove virtual device in Genymotion and Add again the same or other device.
(you will lose your settings and apps in that device)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @warren - actually, it does propose a solution, though it is poorly worded and the solution proposed is a bit desperate.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - it *seems* less than solution-y to me :)

Comment: I believe the proposal is basically "if it's misconfigured, throw it away and make a new one"  Given that Emulators don't have a lot of state that typically matters, are rather complicated and poorly understood, and often created by wizards, it's not all that bad a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I had to change Adapter's address to: **192.168.56.100**.

Then it worked.

Answer (score 2):

(Windows 8) In my case i have changed default RAM from 1GB to 2GB on Genymotion and it gave this error. When i changed it back to 1GB it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i started device from genymotion and then started the device from Virtualbox as well. It helped me.

Answer (score 1):

try to clear the cache in genymotion Setting -> Misc -> Clear cache.

Check this image

maybe it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick i use. Go to http://androvm.org/blog/download/ and download the latest AndroidVm.

Genymotion is the extention of AndroidVM.

Answer (score 0):

This problem keeps cropping up intermittently on my computer and usually, it happens when my computer is running low on system resources (mostly available RAM) and a sure-fire way to fix this (this at least has always worked for me) is to disable the **VirtualBox Host-Only Network** adapter and re-enable it.

If you have multiple virtual adapters, you'll have to find out which of those is used by Genymotion's virtual device and disable and re-enable it. You can find that out by starting VirtualBox and looking here:
[image: screenshot of VirtualBox running a Genymotion virtual device]

You can read about enabling/disabling virtual adapters [here](https://www.softether.org/4-docs/1-manual/4._SoftEther_VPN_Client_Manual/4.3_Virtual_Network_Adapter#Enabling_and_Disabling_a_Virtual_Network_Adapter)

Answer (score 0):

I'm running OSX. The solutions suggested didn't work for me. I'm using OSX Yosemite. I restarted my Mac then I uninstalled VirtualBox by launching the uninstall script (which is shown when you launch the dmg of VirtualBox) then reinstalled it. I also uninstalled and reinstalled Genymotion. Now everything is working smooth.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue and *none* of the suggestions I found anywhere helped, unfortunately. 
The good news, however, is that the latest versions work without any hacks!
I'm referring to Windows 7 host here.

genymotion-2.5.4.exe

VirtualBox-5.0.5-102814-Win.exe (download from [test builds](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds))

Edit: This stopped working again after updates so I gave up on Genymotion. The new Android emulator in SDK performs just as well, has great functionaly, and works without hiccups.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Windows 10 and had the same problem. I resolved it updating the VirtualBox to version 5.1.5. I hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

Mine was working fine on Windows 10 (Creator update edition) but then suddenly stopped working after I had been messing with Homegroups and trying to share a file between our office network. Not really sure what caused it. Has taken me over a week of doing all of the various suggestions above with no luck. Finally, ran a few things that fixed it at last!

IMPORTANT: To be honest, of all the things I ran below, I don't really know which one fixed it. I have a feeling that the IPv6 disabling tool would probably solve this straight away without the additional stuff. Maybe worth running that first to see what happens!

Here's what fixed mine:-

- Removed virtual devices from Genymotion
- Went into VirtualBox (Files -> Virtual Host Manager) and removed the host only adapters.
- Opened command prompt as administrator. Type "cmd" into your search windows search bar, right-click on it and select "Run as Administrator").
- Ran the following commands in order to put everything back to defaults and reset it all.
- `netsh winsock reset catalog` [reference](http://www.sysprobs.com/fixed-windows-10-limited-connectivity-not-getting-ip-from-dhcp)
- `netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log`[same as above](http://www.sysprobs.com/fixed-windows-10-limited-connectivity-not-getting-ip-from-dhcp)
- `ipconfig /release`
- `ipconfig /renew`
- Disable IPV6 using Microsoft's tool found here [Disable IPv6 or its components](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929852/how-to-disable-ipv6-or-its-components-in-windows) (I downloaded and ran the one called Disabled IPv6 on all nontunnel interfaces)
- Restarted computer
- I was using Avast anti-virus. Uninstalled that too to completely remove that from the equation temporarily. I had already been disabling it temporarily whilst trying all the other solutions with no luck. Figured I'd uninstall it for certainty.
- Installed Genymotion 2.12.0-vbox (with VirtualBox which should be 5.2.6)
- After it installs, open up Oracle VM VirtualBox and go to File->Check for updates and you should be told there's an update to 5.2.8 at the time of this post. Install that.
- Now go to GenyMotion and add a new device. Should work! (I didn't tweak anything in VirtualBox, didn't change anything to anything else - it just worked as is for me).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to use host's internal GPU chip to connect display instead of external GPU. In my case, at first, I used GTX 970 chip, but Genymotion doesn't boot emulator. After I connect monitor to internal GPU chip inside CPU, it works.