# Unable to start Genymotion Virtual Device - Virtualbox Host Only Ethernet Adapter Failed to start

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

I'm using Genymotion v13.0 on Windows 8 Pro to create Virtual Device successfully, but when I try to run it I get this error: `Unable to start Genymotion Virtual Device.`

Screenshot:

[image]

Trying to run it via Virtualbox, I got this error message:
`Virtualbox Host Only Ethernet Adapter Failed to start`

Screenshot:

[image]

Virtual Device previously could run well until I got this issue.

Can someone please tell me how to Fix it?

Comment: Whenever I have trouble with VirtualBox, it is always related to Hyper-V.  Their strained relationship has caused a lot of troubles.  In my case of this error message, I had to  Hyper-V Manager to delete two VirtualBox related adapters (Hyper-V Manager > Actions (on the right) > Virtual Switch Manager > Select the VB related switch > Remove)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641423/not-able-to-start-genymotion-device/32818162#32818162

Comment: not a single answer worked for me ? Did you get it resolved anyhow ?

Answer (score 31):

This worked for me using GenyMotion 2.0.3 and VirtualBox 4.3.6.  My problem was I have an existing host-only adaptor that is used by Vagrant.  I can't simply delete it, it will trash my Vagrant VM.

Create a new host-only adaptor in the Virtual Box global settings.
Give it a separate address space from any existing host-only adaptors.  For example, I set mine up as follows, where I also have a vboxnet0 (used by Vagrant) that uses `192.168.56.x`

**name:**  `vboxnet1`
**IPV4 address:** `192.168.57.1`
**mask:**         `255.255.255.0`

**DHCP:**
address `192.168.57.100`
mask:  `255.255.255.0`
low bounds:  `192.168.57.101`
high bound: `192.168.57.254`

Then, edit your existing GenyMotion VM to use this host-only adaptor, and restart it from GenyMotion.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the hint! i did repair on vbox host-only adaptor and windows succeeded to fix it. since then Geny Motion works. by the way,  in Geny Motion docs they say, you can delete the adapter next run genymotion will create it again

Answer (score 21):

I have a same problem and I solve it with this :

1. Open Windows Network Connections
2. Right click on `VirtualBox Host only` adapter that created
3. Choose properties
4. Check `"VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking driver"`
5. disable and Enable the adapter

[image]

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue and this fixed it:

Go to **Network and Sharing Center** > **Change adapter settings** and enable these:

- Local Area Connection (if it's disabled)
- VirtualBox Host-Only Network

I think that enabling the second will do the job, but I did the first anyways.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks it works for me, actually 2 VirtualBox Host-Only Network are created there so I disable second (VirtualBox Host-Only Network #2 ) and enable first (VirtualBox Host-Only Network) and everything working statrt :) thanks :)

Answer (score 13):

It may be because of you assigned more than 50 % RAM memory to your emulator.

Open `Oracle VM --> Settings --> General` And then Decrease memory assigned to the device.

And in `Newer Versions`,
Open `Oracle VM --> Settings --> System --> MotherBoard Tab` And then Decrease memory assigned to the device

Answer (score 8):

In Win10 it might be helpful to [download VirtualBox latest version](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).

It was the only thing that solved it for me. Hope it will save someone some time and trouble.

Comment: Thank's. This is the only option which works on Wib 10

Answer (score 5):

The following resolved the problem for me:

1. Go to Control Panel -> Network and Internet -> change adapter settings
   Right click on VirtualBox Host-Only Network and select properties
   The following options must be ticked

   - client for microsoft networks
   - virtualBox bridged network driver
   - qos pocket scheduler
   - file and printer sharing for microsoft network

   If see another program select and uninstall it.
2. In VirtualBox go to File -> Preferences -> Network
   Double click on VirtualBox Host-Only ethernet adapter
   Edit like this:
   IPV4 address: `192.168.56.1` mask: `255.255.255.0`
   DHCP: address `192.168.56.100` mask: `255.255.255.0`
   low bounds: `192.168.56.101` high bound: `192.168.56.254`
   Restart or log off your windows and start genymotion
   If that didn't solve your problem in VirtualBox go to File -> Preferences -> Network and delete Host-Only ethernet adapter.

Comment: Just checking VirtualBox Bridged Mode in the adapter settings worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Open Virtual Box. Select your virtual Android Device and click on Settings.

[image]

Select Network.

[image]

Make sure "Enable Network Adapter" box is checked. Also Make sure "Attached to:" has "Host-only Adapter selected". Note the name of the adapter.

[image]

Open Settings and click on "Network & Internet"

[image]

In the window that opens click on "Change Adapter Options"

[image]

In the window that opens you can find many Network names listed. Find the network name that matches with the network name that you noted earlier in the Virtual Box.

[image]

Note if that network is Enabled or Disabled.

If the network is Disabled, right click and click Enable.

If the network is Enabled, right click, click Disable and then again click Enable.

[image]

Close the window, open Genymotion and start your Virtual Device. The device should now boot without any error.

Answer (score 3):

Select your`VM -> Settings -> Network ->` Disable the `Network Adapter` (It will be re-configured by Genymotion)

Start the Android Image again in Genymotion UI **(not in Virtualbox)**, It should work now!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in Mac OS, it was a bug in VirtualBox V5.0.2 and fixed in V5.0.3, I installed V5.0.3 and no more problem

Answer (score 1):

It seems your VirtualBox installation doesn't work correctly. You should try to reinstall/upgrade VirtualBox so that during the installation process it fixes this "Interface not found" issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and figured it out today. I had to release the existing virtual drives before Genymotion would allow me to create a NEW virtual drive. Once you click create new drive, it prompts you to login to your Genymotion cloud account. Now I am actually able to run it. Hope this helps.

Edit* Also tried reinstalling AND repairing Virtualbox multiple times and still got same error. Only until I released the existing virtual drives did it start working.

Answer (score 1):

As it mentioned above assigning more than 50 % RAM memory to your emmulator.

For me fixed this way too.

My machine have 8GB and I assigned 4GB for per device. Resetting it solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. it works for me. :)

I also disabled [Hyper-V](http://www.poweronplatforms.com/enable-disable-hyper-v-windows-10-8/) to makes mine work.

[Genymotion FAQ](https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#windows-ten-start-impossible)

To date, VirtualBox is not yet fully compatible with Windows 10. As Genymotion relies on the use of VirtualBox in the background, some problems may arise. If you have any troubles running Genymotion on Windows 10, we first recommend that you put VirtualBox in a clean state. To do so:

1. Uninstall VirtualBox.Reboot your computer if prompted by the installer.
2. Install the version of VirtualBox recommended for Windows 10
   Reboot your computer if prompted by the installer.
3. Open VirtualBox and go to File > Preferences > Network.
4. Remove all existing host-only networks by clicking Description 1.
5. Start Genymotion a first time.
6. In the event of a failure, start Genymotion a second time.

If Genymotion still doesn’t run, you can manually configure a host-only network:

1. Open VirtualBox and go to File > Preferences > Network.
2. Add a new host-only network by clicking Description 1.
3. Edit its configuration by clicking Description 1.
4. In the Adapter tab, set the following values:
       IPv4 Address: 192.168.56.1
       IPv4 Network Mask: 255.255.255.0
5. In the DHCP Server tab, set the following values:
       Check Enable Server.
       Server Address: 192.168.56.100
       Server Mask: 255.255.255.0
       Lower Address Bound: 192.168.56.101
       Upper Address Bound: 192.168.56.254

Answer (score 1):

in my case there was 2 reasons (checked) that my genymotion device couldn't run on windows 10/64bit

## 1. VPN was running and connected

## 2. amount of "base memory" :

> run virtual box > choose your device in the list > Settings > System (left list) > set your base memory on 1024

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to resolve mine:

1. Open VirtualBox and check the new machine that is created for you by GenyMotion
2. Right Click on it and choose **Settings** then go to the **Network** section/tab
3. In **Adapter 1** tab, It should be attached to **Host-Only Adapter**. Check what is the name of the used adapter **Name** then close it.
4. Open **File|Preferences** in **Virtualbox**, then go to **Network** section/tab
5. Under **Host-only Networks** tab, find the same name you have already gotten in step 3.
6. Double click on that name and apple the following configuration

   - Adapter Tab:
   - `IPv4 Adapter: 192.168.65.1`
   - `IPV4 Network Mask: 255.255.255.0`
   - DHCP Server:
   - Check "Enable Server"
   - Server Address: `192.168.65.100`
   - Server Mask: `255.255.255.0`
   - Lower Address Bound: `192.168.65.101`
   - Higher Address Bound: `192.168.65.255`

Answer (score 0):

In Mac, Open Oracle Virtual Box and Goto VirtualBox -> Preferences -> Network. Select the tab'Host Only Networks' & delete vboxnet0. It will be recreated next time you launch genymotion emulator.

Comment: Deleting the existing host only nework adapter finally solved the issue for me on Windows. (Note that this adapter might be used by other machines.)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the version of your genymotion and virtualbox. The genymotion 2.5.3 would work better with virtualbox 4.3.30.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem, and setting up the virtual network configurations did not work. I found this then:
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=70199

Virtualbox seems to vhave a bug in recent releases.
Reinstall it using cmd prompt, and use this as arguments for the executable : -msiparams `NETWORKTYPE=NDIS5`

This did the trick to me. I'm on windows 10, using the `VirtualBox-5.0.10-104061-Win` version.
Note that, this seems not to be a problem with genymotion only.
Hope I spare you some time. I sure spent more than I thought it would take me.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.Run VirtualBox **as administrator**
>
> 2.Go to File -> Preferences -> Network -> Host Only Networks
>
> 3.Add a new one or just edit and delete all existed

```
Adapter Tab:
        IPv4 Address:        192.168.0.201
        IPv4 Network Mask:   255.255.255.0
    DHCP Server Tab:
        Server Address:      192.168.0.100
        Server Mask:         255.255.255.0
        Lower Address Bound: 192.168.0.101
        Upper Address Bound: 192.168.0.199
```

At fast open VirtualBox and then open Genymotion. It then not work just change the Address and try again and restart your PC.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with the new NDIS6 driver, you can install it to use the old NDIS5 driver

Steps I followed:

```
1.Uninstall Virtualbox and try reinstalling it using command prompt.
2. Run command Prompt in administrative mode;
3.Check your Network Drivers if you are using NDIS6 or 6.+ ;
  Write >VirtualBox-5.0.11-104101-Win.exe -msiparams NETWORKTYPE=NDIS5;
4.Now Follow the install steps and finish installation steps.
5. Now try starting device with VirtualBox.
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just download and install the latest version of Virtual box, run it then run the emulator and viola, it will be up and running. This one worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just download latest **Virtualbox** version. Is works for me.

Answer (score 0):

after 2 days searching in web, i found it's related to issue with the new NDIS6 driver, so you can install it to use the old NDIS5 driver

Try installing Old Version of Virtual Box (run as administrator)

VirtualBox-5.x.x

VirtualBox 5.2.6 worked for me
Windows 10 , Genymotion 3.0.3

Answer (score 0):

**Genymotion problem solved**

I have tried all the solutions to solve the Genymotion issue in which it says failed to create a virtual host network i worked on it like for 2 days but then I tried to reset my networks and it works And now Genymotion is working correctly.
Steps of this solution are:-

- First go on settings.
- Then click on Network and internet.
  [This interface will appear and after that click on Network reset your problem will solved after the Machine restarts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTPOZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

After 6 hours of searching

In the VM Virtual box go to Tools -> Network Manager -> remove all Host-Only Networks

or if your vm is old version go to File -> preferences -> Network and remove all  Host-Only Networks

then open the genyMotion and start your virtual device . It will work

[image]