# Virtual Box can not be opened after windows 10 updates

Tags: android, windows-10, virtualbox, genymotion

I downloaded Genymotion with virtual box and it worked perfectly before. But after windows10 update and downloading some other software, Genymotion complains

```
" virtual box can not start the virtual device"
```

. I have uninstall and reinstalled Genymotion. It does not work. I have done some research. I tried running virtualBox.exe as administrator, but still could not open Virtual Box. And the property of the virtualBox HostOnly
network - VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged network driver, is checked by default. I really could not find any other idea to solve this problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looks like this has been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106436/unable-to-start-genymotion-virtual-device-virtualbox-host-only-ethernet-adapte

Comment: My problem is I could not open the Virtual Box interface.

Comment: What leads you to believe that the Windows 10 updates are responsible for breaking the virtualbox software?

Comment: I did not touch that project for a few days. The only difference I could think about is Windows 10 updates.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install newest VirtualBox (5.1.x) will solve this problem.