# Unable to run virtual box and emulator in Genymotion

Tags: android, automation, virtualbox, appium, genymotion

I am unable to run virtual box and emulator in Genymotion.I am getting error as "Unable to start virtual devie".To solve this error , I have tried to start "Oracle virtual VM box" as administartor.But I am not able to launch virtual VM box and its not working.

Attached screen capture for reference.[image: Error screen]

[image: Not able to launch VM device]

Comment: did you check logs?

Comment: How to check that one?

Comment: click on that link or check folder name log/logs in desktop or vm directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to start Genymotion Virtual Device - Virtualbox Host Only Ethernet Adapter Failed to start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106436/unable-to-start-genymotion-virtual-device-virtualbox-host-only-ethernet-adapte)

Answer (score 0):

We need to use the virtual device mentioned in the genymotion FAQ page.
https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#virtual-device-slow

I have update VM device.It has solved the issue