# unable to start genymotion virtual device

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion

the genymotion virtual device could not obtain ip address
for an unkown reason,virtualbox DHCP has not assigned an ip address to virtual device 
i saw many questions as same as mine but they didnt fix it

[image: this is the error msg]

and the network ip

[image]

[image]

Comment: please add links to questions you've tried before.

Comment: in this link the problem was as same as mine but the solution didnt works for me   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641423/not-able-to-start-genymotion-device

Answer (score 6, accepted):

my problem fixed after i deleted the genymotion cashe and i updated the Virtualbox from 4.3.6 to 4.3.8

Answer (score 3):

i had faced same problem now i fixed it  go to 
preference>network tab > host only-networks
then select VIrtualBox - Host Only-Ethernet Adapter then delete it then run your device

Answer (score 1):

[image: I have same problem, i fix it by enable my Virtual Box Host in Network Connections. Make sure its always enable]

I have same problem, i fix it by enable my Virtual Box Host in Network Connections. Make sure its always enable.