# Genymotion on Windows 7 is unable to connect to my virtual device

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, genymotion

I have been using Genymotion for about a month, and it worked well. However, over the past week I have been receiving this error, regardless of my settings:

[image]

"Unable to connect to your virtual device! Genymotion will now stop. Check your VirtualBox network configuration."

and a link to more information:
https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/faq/#collapse-nostart

I have followed the steps there, and the emulator still doesn't work.

I am running Google Nexus 4 - 4.4.2 - API 19 - 768x1280
and have tried with multiple emulators of different APIs and types.
I'm also running a 64-bit Windows 7 operating system.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled both Genymotion and VirtualBox, and I still get the same error. From the emulator preview in VirtualBox, the emulator seems to be running normally, but Genymotion is unable to connect to this device. Running the emulator from VirtualBox seems to work well; unfortunately I can't connect to Eclipse from there.

How do I fix this? The thing is that the emulator worked before, and it doesn't work now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not able to start Genymotion device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641423/not-able-to-start-genymotion-device)

Answer (score 10):

EDIT: It turns out that Genymotion has problems while its user is running a VPN, explaining the connection problems.

I fixed it myself.

The problem mostly involved my Internet connection.

The DHCP server that Genymotion was using was trying to contact the unused IP address 0.0.0.100, which led nowhere.

Therefore, it led the VirtualBox and Genymotion to pick the wrong settings for the DHCP server and the IPv4 address. So my solution was to disable all connections to the Internet before I started Genymotion, and it managed to run without any problems.

Comment: where did you disable Internet ? how ? in VirtualBox, in GenyMotion, in Windows, in Linux ?

Comment: You just saved my life

Answer (score 3):

I faced this problem and I soloved like this:

1) Go to **VirtualBox**  > **File** > **Preference** > **Nework** tab

2) Select **VirtualBox - Host Only-Ethernet Adapter** under  Host-only Networks: and then **delete it**.

3) Restart your virtual device

Answer (score 1):

I had same issues finally I fixed it by following these steps: 
**1)** Open the Oracle VM VirtualBox manager
 
**2)** Settings->Network
 
**3)** Select the Adapter 2 (Adapter 1 is used primary by Genymotion and cannot change)
**4)** Select the NAT
**5)** Restart the VM and Genymotion

Answer (score 0):

Go to VirtualBox -> File -> Preference -> Network
and create a new Bridged Network Adapter. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

A simple "route ADD 192.168.56.100 MASK 255.255.255.255 192.168.56.100" in a command shell with admin rights did the trick...

Answer (score 0):

No other solution worked for me. Only this one worked :

Go to your PC's `Network and Sharing center` and then click on `Virtual box network (Mine was named Ethernet2) -> Properties -> IPv4 -> Properties` :
Now here instead of dynamic IP use a static IP : `192.168.56.10`
That's it. Now, start you Genymotion VM.

I found the solution using [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GYzaj9KWyEQ).