# Genymotion : Virtual Box can't obtain IP (correct DHCP)

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion

My problem is that I obtain the usual error message with Genymotion when I launch it : 
"The Genymotion Virtual device could not obtain an IP address.For an unknown reason, VirtualBox DHCP has not assigned an IP address to virtual device. Run the VirtualBox software to check for issues".

And I read that most people resolved this problem by modifying the preferences of the DHCP server in VirtualBox, yeah.. That works for almost every one, but not for me.

I show you screenshots of my configuration :
[image]

[image]

So I'm wondering if there is any other way to resolved this issue?

Thank you in advance for those who will answer this thread.

PS: My virtualBox is in french.

PS2 : I read the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641423/not-able-to-start-genymotion-device) (and found the same on other sites).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641423/not-able-to-start-genymotion-device/32818162#32818162

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are still searching for a solution I found one by myself :
Check this link :http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SwitchEasilyBetweenVirtualBoxAndHyperVWithABCDEditBootEntryInWindows81.aspx

And once you've done the dual boot with no Hyper-V, delete your terminal and create a new one.