# Genymotion device is not getting an IP from DHCP - VirtualBox : failed to probe driver

Tags: android, ip, virtual-machine, virtualbox, genymotion

In [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) (android device emulator) I'm getting the infamous error "*device did not recive an IP from DHCP"*, however as mentioned below, this curent problem is probably NOT caused by some bad basic network settings.

For the start I've tried almost all solutions from [Not able to start Genymotion device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641423/not-able-to-start-genymotion-device) like re-setting the VirtualBox network preferences, removing the adapter, adding it again, removing it and then recreating it automaticly by re-running Genymotion, allowing promiscuite mode for VMs and so on... however I am still not getting there.

This is the output from the VirtualBox device's console:
[image: virtualbox android device problem]

So I guess it is some virtual device driver problem - but where is the solution?

Many thanks!

PS: running on Windows 7, Virtual device: Samsung Galaxy S5 - 4.4.4 - API 19 - 1080x1920

Comment: Which genymotion & virtual box version? If you have vpn, firewall and anti-virus software have you tried to disable them?

Comment: @pcans GenyMotion 2.3.1,  (latest, bundled with VirtualBox 4.2.12.0), neither antivirus nor firewall has risen a message, but now after restarting a PC it suddenly works both firewall and antivirus is ON, so probably some restart-needed issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try factory re-setting the device in Genymotion, most of the cases this worked and make sure that Virtual network adapter is installed properly and last but not the least verify whether you enabled Virtualisation Technology in BIOS