# Genymotion devices won't start - The Genymotion Virtual device could not obtain an IP address

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtualbox, genymotion

When I create a Genymotion device and try to start it, it says, "The Genymotion Virtual device could not obtain an IP address". I realize this is a common problem and I have looked every where and tried several solutions (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641423/not-able-to-start-genymotion-device)) and none of them have worked for me. I attempted to start the device via Virtual Box and this is a screen shot of what happened.[image]

Comment: In your list of Host-only Networks, do you just have the one?

Comment: Yes, it's called, "Virtual Box Host-Only Ethernet Adapter"

Comment: you can follow this link may be this will help you a lot : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641423/not-able-to-start-genymotion-device

Comment: That's the same post I put in the question for what I have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

This Open your virtual box > click your android virtual > Setting > Network > Set to VirtualBox Host_Only Ethernet Adapter.

Than go to your Network and Sharing Center > open your VirtualBox Connection > Properties > IPv4 > Set all to Auto for DHCP Setting

Note: If you have more than one VirtualBox Host in your Virtual Box Setting try to delete it and leave one

or you can get more info from [this](https://www.genymotion.com/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter#!/support#faq)