# Genymotion won't start

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

I've got problem with Genymotion, it just won't start.

I'm always getting this error:

```
mar 14 20:47:30 [Genymotion] [Error] "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2" : invalid interface. Subnet:  "169.254.41"  Mask:  "255.255.0.0" 
mar 14 20:47:30 [Genymotion] [Error] "Fail to load vboxmanage plugin from C:/Program Files/Genymobile/Genymotion/plugins/" 
mar 14 20:47:30 [Genymotion] [Error] VM Engine failed to load 
mar 14 20:47:30 [Genymotion] [Error] Unable to find VM Engine. Plugin loading aborted.
```

In virtual box i'm getting new host-only adapter after each genymotion start.

I've tried to delete all adapters to setup them by genymotion, setting dhcp for adapters (192.168.56.100 ...), turn on/off Hyper-v, disable firewall and few other tricks.

I cannot set ip for adapter, it always sets to default microsoft address 169.254...

My system is windows 8.1 running on lenovo g510 (i5, ati graphics). Genymotion 2.4.0, VirtualBox 4.3.24.

Does any one have a fresh suggestion? It's driving me crazy :/

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Did you try to reinstall your virtual box?

Comment: Yes, and geny also...

Comment: Try this [solution](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/virtualbox-genymotion-issue-t2862447).

Comment: I did also and problem stays.

Comment: I'm facing problems with genymotion too. What virtual device(like the mobile name) are you trying to start?

Comment: I didn't setup any device. I'm only install genyemotion and virtual box. I've read that device is setup later, after geny starts. But it's not starting...

Comment: Have you ever worked on Genymotion? That is to say, has Genymotion ever worked on your system? And can you give steps that to took to start the Genymotion emulator?

Comment: I've never work with genymotion. I'm working with adv. Firstly I'm install virtualbox (with default options, restart) and next genymotion. Next I'm launching geny without success. All on admin account. 
I don't have any antyvir or something like that. Default win8.

Comment: I'm having this very same issue, the "invalid interface" one, and Genymotion won't start. Tried everything with no success. I'll keep an eye on this question.

Comment: have you tried with a 4.3.12 version of virtualbox?

Comment: Tried with 4.3.12, which is shipped with Genymotion, and the result is always the same. Also tried a bunch of the newest ones with no success.

Comment: Me too. I've try the virtualbox with genymotion installer and always get error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not able to start Genymotion device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641423/not-able-to-start-genymotion-device)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on Windows 8.1, Genymotion 2.4.0 and VirtualBox (tried with both 4.3.12 and 4.3.26). I found a temporary solution through the following steps:

- In Virtual Box: Settings\Network\Host-only Networks remove all host-only Networks
- Disable the Ethernet connection in Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections
- Enable the WiFi connection
- Start Genymotion. After starting successfully a Virtual Machine, it is necessary to remove all host-only networks, close genymotion and open it again to make it work

I know it might not be a solution if you are not lucky enough to have multiple network connections, but it might give you some suggestions for alternative paths to follow.

I am pretty sure our firewall has a configuration that disturbs VirtualBox while creating the Host-only Network (which you can find in Virtual Box\Settings\Network\Host-only Networks).

I am not sure this is related, but on my Ethernet network connection, ping is disabled, whereas it works normally on my WiFi connection.

When Genymotion starts it searches for a valid Host-Only Ethernet Adapter in VirtualBox. if it doesn't find it, it tries to create a new one based on your active network connection. My theory is that if your network connection has some firewall limitations (some sort of blocked ports) the newly created Host-Only Ethernet Adapter doesn't have a valid IP configuration and therefore Genymotion fails to start. If you try to start several times Genymotion, you will find as many Host-only Networks as attempts.

Switching to a network connection that allows to create a valid Host-Only Ethernet Adapter solves the problem and, in my case, created automatically a working Host-only Network with the following parameters (Virtual Box\Settings\Network\Host-only Networks):

Adapter

- IPv4Address: 192.168.31.101
- IPv4 Network Mask: 255.255.255.0

DHCP Server

- Enabled
- Server Address: 192.168.31.100
- Server Mask: 255.255.255.0
- Lower Address Bound: 192.168.31.101
- Upper Address Bound: 192.168.31.254

I had similar problems with previous versions of Genymotion and I was able to successfully use the workaround described here: [Not able to start Genymotion device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641423/not-able-to-start-genymotion-device)

Answer (score 1):

Found this via Google 2 years later.  Genymotion 2.9.0 was freezing on launch with "loading plugins" displayed. Proposed solution didn't work as-is, but finally this did:

- Remove all all host-only Networks in VirtualBox (File->Preferences->Network->Host-Only Networks)
- Start Genymotion *as administrator* so it can re-add them

Answer (score 0):

Same issue also on Windows 8.1, Genymotion 2.4.0 and VirtualBox (both with the bundled VirtualBox version and when installing VirtualBox separately).

I followed the instructions here (depicted for OS X) to manually configure a "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter" within VirtualBox's 'Network' settings:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21486549/2059308

Genymotion then loaded up and worked normally.