# "The Genymotion server is temporarily unavailable" on Windows 7 Enterprise

Tags: genymotion

Can someone help me i am unable to login Genymotion to add devices.
I get message like "The Genymotion server is temporarily unavailable"

I already opened up genymotion and oracle vm box as admin.
Its on Windows 7 Enterprise

Comment: This problem occurs sometimes due to DHCP issues ,Try this answer [Here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21486549/3857029

Answer (score 2):

Are you using proxy server(you didn't mention)?,
If yes go to settings>network and set you proxy settings in genymotion.
Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I see these three scenarios :

1. Most of the time it's the network configuration that is preventing Genymotion to access the data it needs (example : verifying credentials) so **check your network settings and firewall!**
2. When the guys at Genymotion are updating their website and database. Usually it doesn't last long so **you just have to wait a few minutes and retry**.
3. When your credentials are not the good ones. **Try your username and password on the Genymotion website.** If it doesn't' work there then reset your password from the Genymotion website.