# Error "VirtualBox DHCP has not assigned an IP address to virtual device" when starting Genymotion

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

I have Win 8.1 with latest Genymotion 2.5.3 + Virtualbox 4.3.30. Every time I try to open a VM from Genymotion I get "VirtualBox DHCP has not assigned an IP address to virtual device." error after trying every single solution I found on stackoverfow. Most of which are in this post:

[Not able to start Genymotion device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641423/not-able-to-start-genymotion-device)

These are the solutions that did NOT work for me:

1. manually entering IP addresses, network masks and DHCP server as described on several posts (ie 192.168.56.1 etc)
2. deleting network adapters on global options in virtualbox so they get recreated upon start of genymotion.
3. installing a new VM for a generic phone instead of motoX.
4. deleting virtualbox and genymotion and reinstalling from scratch + downloading all VMs again.
5. freeing up RAM to make sure I have most RAM available.
6. changing system RAM resources in VM configuration to 1024 or 2048 or increasing it as far as I could.
7. changing video RAM resources setting.
8. confirmed hyper-V is disabled from windows so that is NOT the issue.
9. setting "promiscuous mode" to: "allow VMs", or "deny", or "allow everything".
10. checking logs on /Users/USER/AppData/Local/Genymobile/ I didn't see anything special even after clearing all.

IF I start the VM from virtualbox (not genymotion) with 1024 MB RAM and 1 CPU, and get the "Android is upgrading" screen and after 57 updates are downloaded I get the Android logo loading and nothing happens or I get "unable to connect to your virtual device". And if I try running it from genymotion, I end up in the very same "classic" DHCP error anyway.

What I CANNOT try: I cannot try downgrading genymotion or virtualbox versions (I don't have old versions). Also I cannot select more than 1 CPU on Virtualbox because of my CPU I guess, so I cannot change that. But this shouldn't help I guess.

Interesting info: I DID get to run the VM successfully both from VirtualBox and from GenyMotion after changing some more settings: I selected "enable PAE/NX on processor" + I changed video memory to just 8MB + I disabled "hardware clock in UTC". But after 30 minutes and several attempts at adding new VMs, I couldn't get to run it again and I am back stuck with the same errors as described.

Can anyone think of further solutions to this issue?