# I can't open my virtual device on Genymotion

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

I added a virtual device and got this error:

*Unable to start the virtual device.*

*The virtual device got no IP address.*

*The VirtualBox DHCP server has not been assigned to an IP address to the virtual device. To find a solution, please start VirtualBox.*

http://i1378.photobucket.com/albums/ah98/prosaviour/Genymotion-Virtualbox/Error_zpspv7nv9hm.png

I checked for solutions online and they said that I have to go to VirtualBox --> File --> Preferences --> Network and change the addresses for "vboxnet0" which is supposed to be under Host-only networks. However, I don't have "vboxnet0" under Host-only networks. I only have "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter".

http://i1378.photobucket.com/albums/ah98/prosaviour/Genymotion-Virtualbox/virtualbox_zps0fygnrob.png

Under "Adapter", IPv4 Address is set to 192.168.56.1 and IPv4 Network Mask is set to 255.255.255.0. Under "DHCP Server", Server Address is set to 192.168.56.100, Server Mask is set to 255.255.255.0, Lower Address Bound is set to 192.168.56.101 and Upper Address Bound is set to 192.168.56.254

http://i1378.photobucket.com/albums/ah98/prosaviour/Genymotion-Virtualbox/adapter_zpsallwan4p.png

http://i1378.photobucket.com/albums/ah98/prosaviour/Genymotion-Virtualbox/DHCP%20server_zpsob27p6df.png

So how do I solve the problem?

Comment: can you open command line prompt (start->run->cmd) and type ipconfig, and show me what you have for `Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network` ?

Comment: IPv4 Address is set to 192.168.56.1 and Subnet Mask is 255.255.255.0

Comment: Here is a complete guide:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641423/not-able-to-start-genymotion-device