# Genymotion does not start

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

[image]i have installed genymotion on my windows laptop but when i start the virtural device from the GENYMOTION it says `Virtual Device got no IP address`
and when i start the virtual device from the VIRTUAL BOX it shows this error:-
[image]

Comment: Have you start device from genymotion or virtual box ?

Comment: when i started from the genymotion it says virtual device got no ip address and when i started from the virtalbox it shows the above screenshot

Comment: Can you take screen shot from open device using genymotion.

Comment: ok wait for a minute

Comment: @SuhasBachewar i have udated the question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641423/not-able-to-start-genymotion-device

Answer (score 1):

Problem is on a VirtualBox network, pls setup for it: IP, DNS, ...
http://column80.com/api.v2.php?a=askubuntu&q=545687