# Genymotion unable obtain ip address

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

i'm trying to use **genymotion** as my android emulator for android studio. And i'm using windows 8. 
But when i try to start the virtual device it gives me "unable to obtain ip address" and so on.
I have tried everything and recently i referred [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=idbEKe7hUlQ) but still no luck.
Is there a better solution for this.?
Thanks in advance.!

Comment: try create new device

Answer (score 1):

An android restart(not system) did the the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through this link [Genymotion is unable to obtain IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641423/not-able-to-start-genymotion-device).

you need to change your configuration inside Genymotion i.e **Virtual box preferences** >> **Network** to access the emulator.

Hopefully this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It was a port-security config that didn't let me to be connected directly, I set NAT config in genymotion.