# Open Virtual Machine Genymotion Network error

Tags: android, genymotion

Error when open Virtual Device Nexus 7 android 5.0 API 21

[image: Error when open Virtual Device Nexus 7 android 5.0 API 21]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641423/not-able-to-start-genymotion-device

Comment: May be this can help. Start Virtual Box, there you will see devices (genymotion devices). Select the device you want and click start...Then a black screen (like cmd appears) .Then open genymotion and start the same device.

Comment: I can't start device in virtualbox i got 1 error "This kernel requires an X86CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU"

Answer (score 0):

[image] If you have tried above solution and still in trouble then enable the Virtuaization in your BIOS. This error occurs if you have not Enabled virtualization in your BIOS.Please Check over it once :) :)

Comment: Yes Niroj thapa when I Enabled virtualization in my BIOS , I got one error
"This kernel requires an X86CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU".

Comment: Download the correct installtion file... you downloaded a 64 bit version but have a 32 bit system. My best guess is that you somehow configured the VM for 32 bit execution instead of 64.

Comment: Thank for your help