# GenyMotion Unable to start the Genymotion virtual device

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

When I run Genymotion, I get the following error:

> Unable to start the Genymotion virtual device.
>
> Unable to configure the network adapter for the virtual device.
>
> Please, check the following points:
> From VirtualBox, in the main parameters of software, check a network adapter "Host-only" is present.
> From VirtualBox, in the Genymotion virtual device parameters, check the first network interface has the type "Host-only". If no, then set this parameter manually.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Try doing as Genymotion is instructing you - check the parameters in Oracle Virtual Box, and post here if that does not help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not able to start Genymotion device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641423/not-able-to-start-genymotion-device)

Comment: use freegate and set proxy in genymotion setting :127.0.0.1 port:8580

Answer (score 80):

Update: Before you read further, I want to notice that I didn't have any problems since I upgraded VirtualBox to 4.3.4.

I use VirtualBox 4.3.2 under Ubuntu 13.10. I had same issue after upgrading from Genymotion 2.0.0 to 2.0.1.

These are the steps I followed to fix this, although I'm not sure which one works for you.

**Step 1.** Start VirtualBox, go to menu File/Preferences menu, go to Network section, select Host-only Networks tab.

If you don't have any adapter defined, then you can create one (as indicated below) or you can ignore step 1 and Genymotion will create it when you try to start the VM.

If you do have an adapter there (vboxnet0) click the edit button. In the edit window, you must have DHCP server enabled AND the IP address and allocation pool of the server must be inside same network as the IP of the network controller. For example, I use:

- IPv4 address/netmask: 192.168.56.1/255.255.255.0 (on Adapter tab)
- DHCP server enabled checked (on DHCP server tab)
- Server address/netmask: 192.168.56.100/255.255.255.0
- Server lower/upper address: 192.168.56.100/192.168.56.254

Still in VirtualBox, select the Android VM you have, click Settings button, select Network section. In the Adapter 1 tab, you should have:

- Enable network adapter checked
- Attached to: Host-only adapter
- Name: vboxnet0

Normally, if you have all these settings, it should work ok, but it didn't for me. So I moved to step 2.

**Step 2.** As indicated by Genymotion, start VirtualBox, go to menu File/Preferences menu, go to Network section, select Host-only Networks tab and delete the defined adapters.

Start your VM in Genymotion. Genymotion will recreate the adapter with proper settings (as described in step 1)

Normally, if step 1 didn't work for you, step 2 should work ok, but it didn't for me. So I moved to step 3.

**Step 3.** Delete and recreate the Android VM in Genymotion (VirtualBox host-only network settings I left as described in step 1).

This solved my issue and Android VM works ok now. Good luck.

Andrei.

Update: A day after posting answer, when I was first starting a VM in genymotion, it gave again same error again and vboxnetdhcp process crashed (and restarted). On second and later start attempts it worked ok. So it might still be some minor issue there with VirtualBox DHCP process.

Update: The issue seems to reside in virtual Box DHCP server which crashes:

```
/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxNetDHCP --network HostInterfaceNetworking-vboxnet0 --trunk-type netflt --trunk-name vboxnet0 --mac-address 08:00:27:72:4C:7B --ip-address 192.168.56.100 --netmask 255.255.255.0 --verbose
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

Deleting and recreating the VM fixed again the issue. Maybe Genymotion sends some invalid data to VBox DHCP that makes it crash (still a VBox bug though).

Comment: Also had to increase my system resources in addition to your 1st fix, but now I'm good to go. Thank you!

Comment: Perfect that solved my problem as well. i am using windows 7 VMBox 3.2.1.

Comment: None of the above worked for me. I'm unable to start just this device: Preview 2.3 Nexus S

Comment: @Arjun_U Try upgrading VirtualBox to 4.3.4

Comment: Step 1 fixed my issues

Comment: Step 2 works and fixed 2 of my devices, but with galaxy s the problem still persist O.o?

Comment: Step 2 fixed my problem

Comment: Upgrade VirtualBox and everything's going to be fine then :)

Comment: Hey, can I let the genimotion to use NAT network in VIrtualBox, without host-only network, I hate it:
- It still running when the emulator stopped, and may it burn my laptop battery?
-When I turn on Airplane mode (windows), the network tray icon always display an yellow "!" error
-The genimotion auto re-create a host-only on startup

Comment: @user2447581 no, you can not. Genymotion will not start if it can't connect to the VM via the host-only network. If you want to disable host-only network, you can do that if you start the VM via VirtualBox UI (instead of Genymotion). However, you won't have the Android device UI for your VM (you won't have home, rotate, menu, etc buttons)

Answer (score 25):

If as me you've tried everything above (especially windows 10 users ) and nothing helped here is what eventually solved the issue. The solution was ridiculously easy but took a day to figure it out.

1. Recommended to remove host only network adapter from virtual box, to do that open virtual box File->Preferences->Network->select tab host only network adapter->remove all (no worries when you start a vm from genymotion it will create new). Now open Genymotion and try to start your virtual device. Get the error ? that's good follow second step
2. (What actually fixed the issue) Go to Control Panel->Network and Internet->Network Connections, on there you should see an Ethernet network adapter that virtual box created ( it was created automatically when you started device from genymotion), so right click on it then Properties then CHECK VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver, see image attached. [image: see image attached]
3. You're done. Start your device from genymotion, should work now.

Comment: It worked. Not exactly as described - it required a few restarts of GenyMotion, and setting this property for 3 or 4 different adapters that it created - but it worked. This is the way to go. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: It might also help to Disable and then Enable the adapter (from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35025393/1558717)).

Answer (score 6):

Follow following step to work genemotion like charm.

1. Open Oracle VM virtual Box
2. **File** -> **Preferences** ( ctrl + g ) -> open one dialog box -> select **Network**  -> select Host only network choose you adapter ( there are three button on right side -add -remove -Edit host only nw.,

   If you dont have any adapter then create.
3. After selecting your adapater choose Edit **Edit host only network(space)**
4. Open one dialog box then choose **DHCP server**  choose **Enable Server** and fill all ip addresses.

   like

   IPv4 address/netmask: 192.168.56.1/255.255.255.0 (on Adapter tab)

   DHCP server enabled checked (on DHCP server tab)

   Server address/netmask: 192.168.56.100/255.255.255.0

   Server lower/upper address: 192.168.56.100/192.168.56.254
5. Give ok.
6. In starting of the oracle virtual machine there are different tab like General ,system , Display ,storage,Network etc.. **Click on Network**
7. Open one dialog box, select **Enable Network adapter**  attached to ->**host only network**
   and main thing is that in Name tab, choose adapter that you are choosing in preference **both adapter much be match**  example you choose virtualbox...2 then here also choose that one.
8. Ok.
9. Now play your genemotion. if again error come then again restart to play you succedd.
10. :)

See full video here to see above all step and work well with genemotion.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YuJ6ZfudFp8

Comment: not able to set 4th step of your solution got this error : Failed to save DHCP parameter. 
Details Log:
Server address within range bounds.
Result Code: 
NS_ERROR_INVALID_ARG (0x80070057)
Component: 
VirtualBoxWrap
Interface: 
IVirtualBox {9570b9d5-f1a1-448a-10c5-e12f5285adad}
Callee: 
IDHCPServer {00c8f974-92c5-44a1-8f3f-702469fdd04b}

@nirav Mehta please help me

Comment: Server address should not be within range i.e between ...100 and ...254 as your lower and upper bonds above, select a number like ...99 for the address

Comment: There is no more "Edit" in the latest versions.

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly the same problem as you, tried everything, but the solution is really easy:

1. Open Network and Sharing Center
2. Change adapter settings
3. Right click your Virtualbox host-only adapter and select Properties
   Enable "Virtualbox NDIS6 Bridget Networking Driver"

Answer (score 4):

I'm running OSX. The solutions suggested didn't work for me. I'm using OSX Yosemite. I restarted my Mac then I uninstalled VirtualBox by launching the uninstall script (which is shown when you launch the dmg of VirtualBox) then reinstalled it. I also uninstalled and reinstalled Genymotion. Now everything is working smooth.

Answer (score 4):

I was struggling with this for a while and finally found a solution on Windows 10.

*Steps*:

Network and Sharing Center  >  Change Adapter Settings > Right Click on **VirtualBox Host-Only Network** ( If you have multiple do the following to all of them ) > Properties > Check the **VirtualBox NDUS6 Bridged Networking Driver**

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the only option was to **remove** the VM and **download it again**. No re-configuration of the host-only adapter did not help, I used different addressing of DHCP. Virtual Box I updated to version 4.3.4 and Genymotion to 2.0.2

Answer (score 2):

After you have updated the latest GenyMotion Version to 2.10 from 2.02...

1. Open GenyMotion
2. Go to the List of your 2.02 Devices
3. Left click the item and then right click on the menu to **Delete all your 2.02 Virtual Devices
4. Click the Add button at the top to add a New Device. Log into your account
5. Select the device you want. You can only select one device at a time
6. Click the Next button. Notice the Version number says - 2.10. There is other info about the device here.
7. Your device will start downloading to your GenyMotion Folder on the Drive **C.
   8  After you download it, double click it to open up the Virtual Device like you normally would.
8. Repeat for other device you want

** C:\%Users%\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion\deployed

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is old, but in case someone is searching google i think i should mention what fixed my problem. After the 3 steps from above the error message was gone but the screen still stayed black and opening an .apk got stuck on file transfer. It had something to do with a VPN application (in my case Hamachi). I just closed it and then the emulator ran fine. This post prompted me to do so: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/genymotion-users/network/genymotion-users/QAX_UrAzEn0/o947IXpsDuIJ

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and tired all the above solutions and did not work for me!
the problem was because multiple networks make conflict between VMware and VirtualBox, and other VPN connections.
The solution i followed is:

- **solution 1 :**

uninstall virtualbox and reinstall the last update of it

- **solution 2** :

If solution 1 not working, try this uninstalling all VPN programs, VirtualBox, Genymotion and reinstalled VirtualBox and Genymotion again.
both solutions worked with me

Answer (score 1):

**Firewall might be the cause, just try disabling it**
In my case it was due to the firewall. I tried all these suggestions in the answers and none of them worked for me. Finally I disabled the firewall It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For windows users:   **Disable Hyper-V and its tools**

If you are a windows user, the problem might simply be because of having multiple virtualization technologies in your system.

You might be having Hyper-V and its related features enabled. Just simply turning them off and rebooting your system can do you help sometimes.

[image]

Here is how you do it:

1. Fire up **Run** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)
2. Type **appwiz.cpl** and press enter
3. Head over to **Turn Windows features on or off**
4. Find **Hyper-V** and deselect everything under it.
5. Press **Ok** and give your system a restart.

Fireup your genymotion and check to see if it works again.
If there is an error prompt saying something like DHCP cant assign IP... just try restarting your genymotion application.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occured for me one time when I had already opened the built-in Android Emulator (AVD). Check if you turned off it before start changing anything in settings.

Answer (score 0):

For `VIrtual Box 5.x` - the settings from above comments are set automatically

Now for the error:

1.Make sure that you have enough `Processor(s)` and `Base Memory` - so the PC can support VM configuration(I use 1 procesor and 1024MB for all VM's)

2.Delete any unused VM from `Genymotion` and `Oracle VirtualBox Manager` - seems to reserve their configuration, though you use it or not(that specific  VM)

Answer (score 0):

I had a same kind of issue starting Genymotion on Ubuntu 16.04 and solved it in this way https://medium.com/@avanvitharana/genymotion-on-ubuntu-16-04-cb8ef8fc70e9#.6y0bgmmjb

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me when I start `Gennymotion` in `Admin` mode

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure to update your Oracle VM Virtual Box. I tried everything but later realized that the issue was due to the use of older version of Virtual Box.

Answer (score 0):

The number of CPUs is insufficient. Select 1 CPU in Genymotion and restart the device.

[image: Genymotion device configuration]

Answer (score 0):

Please download new Virtual Box and Install it.

For Download Virtual Box use below link:

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

These works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should run Genymotion as root under Linux:

```
sudo ./genymotion
```

I have installed Genymotion as a regular user, and got the same nasty VM complaints of not being able to initialize KVM cause it's being taken by some other application. The solution was to start Genymotion by the root user, remember: you'll have to download all the smartphone images once again.

Answer (score -2):

If all the other answers here fail (you can check that you have a correctly created host-only network in VirtualBox, which is basically what other answers here come down to):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33733454/586754 (with screenshot) worked for me.

Basically, go to Windows network adapter settings for the "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter" and check "VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver".

This made both Genymotion and Xamarin Android Player work again.