# Genymotion on Ubuntu 13.04 won't connect to virtual device

Tags: android, ubuntu, genymotion

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04. I've installed VirtualBox 4.3.6 and Genymotion 2.0.3. After installation, I downloaded the Galaxy S4 - 4.2.2 image, as well as a few others. All of them encounter the same problem: After clicking Play, I get the window for the virtual device, but then I get an error:

> Unable to connect to your virtual device! Genymotion will now stop. Check your VirtualBox network configuration.

The VirtualBox network is configured like this:

- No NAT networks
- One Host-only Network, vboxnet0

  - Adapter

    - IPv4 Address: 192.168.56.1
    - IPv4 Network Mask: 255.255.255.0
    - IPv6 Address: fe80:0000:0000:0000:0800:27ff:fe00:0000
    - IPv6 Network Mask Length: 64
  - DHCP Server

    - Server Address: 192.168.56.1
    - Server Mask: 255.255.255.0
    - Lower Address Bound: 192.168.56.100
    - Upper Address Bound: 192.168.56.254

After hitting Play, I look in the genymotion-player.log and see the following related to networking:

```
Jan 10 00:51:12 [Genymotion Player] [Debug] "Name:            vboxnet0
GUID:            786f6276-656e-4074-8000-0a0027000000
DHCP:            Disabled
IPAddress:       192.168.56.1
NetworkMask:     255.255.255.0
IPV6Address:     fe80:0000:0000:0000:0800:27ff:fe00:0000
IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength: 64
HardwareAddress: 0a:00:27:00:00:00
MediumType:      Ethernet
Status:          Up
VBoxNetworkName: HostInterfaceNetworking-vboxnet0
```

...and, a bit later in the log:

```
Jan 10 00:51:12 [Genymotion Player] [Debug] "NetworkName:    HostInterfaceNetworking-

vboxnet0
IP:             192.168.56.1
NetworkMask:    255.255.255.0
lowerIPAddress: 192.168.56.100
upperIPAddress: 192.168.56.254
Enabled:        Yes

NetworkName:    NatNetwork
IP:             10.0.2.3
NetworkMask:    255.255.255.0
lowerIPAddress: 10.0.2.4
upperIPAddress: 10.0.2.254
Enabled:        Yes
```

Still later in the log:

```
Jan 10 00:51:13 [Genymotion Player] [Debug] Virtual Machine started. 
Jan 10 00:51:13 [Genymotion Player] [Debug] Waiting for an IP address...
```

A couple of seconds later:

```
Jan 10 00:51:18 [Genymotion Player] [Debug] Genymotion system started. Attributed IP address:  "192.168.56.3"
```

And then, when it fails:

```
Jan 10 00:51:24 [Genymotion Player] [Error] Unable to connect player to virtual machine: "192.168.56.3"
```

I've tried other workarounds suggested:

- Uninstall / reinstall Genymotion
- Uninstall / reinstall VirtualBox
- Downgrade VirtualBox to 4.2
- Delete and redownload the device images
- Delete and allow Genymotion to recreate the host-only network

I also should state that I do not have a firewall, so I'm confident there's no issue arising because of interference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that I'm running both VMWare and, to support Genymotion, VirtualBox.

I discovered this with help from the Genymotion support, who pointed out that when I run:

```
sudo netstat -nm
```

the result is something like:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.100.2   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
172.16.30.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 vmnet1
192.168.56.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 vmnet8
192.168.56.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 vboxnet0
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

I was able to fix this by going into VirtualBox, and from the Network section of the Preferences dialog, I changed every reference to 192.168.56.* in the vboxnet0 configuration to 192.168.57.*.

THANK YOU Genymotion support team!

Comment: Hi @jgindin, do you use this solution for the latest version of VirtualBox? It seems that when I do this I cannot change the DHCP server IP from *.56.* to *.57.*.

Comment: Sorry @seenickcode, I haven't been using Genymotion lately.

Comment: Hi @jgindin thanks for the reply. For anyone else: this basically helped me, go here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922077/genymotion-unable-to-start-the-genymotion-virtual-device then search for the answer with "These are the steps I followed to fix this, although I'm not sure which one works for you."

Comment: killing the standard DHCP might also wok; `VBoxManage dhcpserver remove --netname HostInterfaceNetworking-vboxnet0`