# Genymotion device doesn't start up

Tags: ip, virtualbox, dhcp, genymotion

This question might seem a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641423/not-able-to-start-genymotion-device) but it's not because i've tried almost everything in this world to get a device run in genymotion.
Everytime i try to start a device i get the error:

[image: Error]

after some minutes looking for the log file i could found it and the last line (where it get stuck) says this:

```
Mar 27 04:01:31 [Genymotion Player] [Error] Can't detect device IP address
```

The error is explanatory itself but i don't know how to make it detect the device ip address, things i've tried are:

1. Deleting all Host-only network in VirtualBox
2. Updating VirtualBox to last version.
3. Downgrading version.
4. Delete vm and recreate it.
5. Erase and download same device.
6. Fill manually network configuration (was a silly attempt but the error is driving me crazy)

By the way the Firewall isn't blocking the application because i checked myself.

I tried all the step from this [answer and also none of them didn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922077/genymotion-unable-to-start-the-genymotion-virtual-device/20018833#20018833)

I had a Linux distro called **Elementary Luna** and i installed genymotion and it worked perfectly on elementary luna but i had to came back to window due driver issue that doesn't let the distro boot up again. I can't use the emulator that came with the Android SDK because i have AMD processor and my CPU model isn't good, i don't even get 1 fps with the sdk emulator. But when i was using Genymotion back in linux i could run it at 20/30fps.

Forgot to say i'm on Window 8.1 Enterprise.

Do i have to fix and come back to linux again to test my android app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately I could solve it downgrading to Window 7, i think the problem was with Window 8.1, now i'm using Windows 7 Ultimate and it's working perfectly.

**Edit**

I came back to Window 8.1 and everything is working perfectly, i still don't know what the problem was, but it's working now.

Comment: For anyone still having issues, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/32818162/202166