# Genymotion refuses to start with "The Genymotion virtual device could not get an IP address."

Tags: android, emulation, virtualbox, genymotion

I am freaking out right now, I can't afford to lose another day of work trying to fix this stupid error (as well as can't get a real device at the moment). 
I am using an older laptop, so using the already slow Android emulator provided by Google isn't an option.

Genymotion was working fine for around a month, and now it refuses to start no matter what I do. I get "Unable to start the Genymotion virtual device. The Genymotion virtual device could not get an IP address. For an unknown reason, VB DHCP has not assigned an IP address to the virtual device."

What I have tried based on other answers I have read here on SO:

- Completely removing antivirus and disabling firewall
- Trying to start up Genymotion with network disabled
- Removing the host-only network
- Upgrading VB to latest / downgrading VB
- Manuallly configuring IP. This works once but then it breaks after a second time
- There are only three other programs installed and it is rather a fresh copy of Windows

Comment: Is it a virtual device or the Genymotion software itself that is not starting?

Comment: @shkschneider I think it is the virtual device. Here is a picture of a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678159/genymotion-device-doesnt-start-up

Comment: I already had that. Removing and creating a new (same) virtual device fixed my (weird) issue. Might work for you...

Comment: @shkschneider I tried that all day yesterday too :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize it's an old question, have you had any luck? Maybe check to be sure your DHCP Client service is running. This happened to me, and the service was disabled so I enabled, set startup type to "automatic" and did not get the error again. Good luck.

Comment: no i stopped using genymotion a long time ago, i just ended up getting a new computer and can now run the emulator fine :p

Answer (score 0):

When you get the error like in this thread [Genymotion device doesn't start up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678159/genymotion-device-doesnt-start-up) just try to start task manager and close the running process named VBoxHeadLess , VBoxNetDHCP and VBoxInterface and then try to start again the simulator. I always do that to fix this issue and it worked for me perfectly. 
Else you should try to uninstall Genymotion and re-install it again

Answer (score 0):

If someone's still facing similar issue, here's how I fixed this on Mac OS Sierra: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41117704/4331787