# Genymotion - The virtual device got no IP Address

Tags: android, genymotion

I already tried doing this. [Genymotion refuses to start with "The Genymotion virtual device could not get an IP address."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717739/genymotion-refuses-to-start-with-the-genymotion-virtual-device-could-not-get-an) but nothing happend.
And also here [Not able to start Genymotion device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641423/not-able-to-start-genymotion-device).

Is it me? Who is being forsaken? Or is it my Lenovo laptop who's specs are just 
AMD-E1 Dual Core 1.0ghz (But I can run VS Studio 2013 just fine)

4gb RAM

Windows 8.1
 
But I found something weird. in most of the tutorial here in stackoverflow. in the **File** -> **Preference** -> **Network** the `host-only network` is `vboxnet0` whilst on me it is `VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter` I tried checking the Adapter and DHCP settings nothing is wrong.

 Here is a printscreen when I try running it in Virtualbox
[image: Something]

Answer (score 34):

I have faced the same issue with genymotion. Follow these steps, may you can solve the issue

1. Open Oracle VM Virtual box
2. Select the custom phone ->right click->settings->General->Basic
3. Change the type to your current OS
4. Choose Version of the windows

In My case: I'm using Windows 10 -so, I Chose other Windows(64 bit)

Comment: Voila...this tip worked in  windows 7 64 bit version..thnks man

Comment: it didn't change anything

Comment: The OS setting in virtual box is supposed to be for the guest os not the host

Answer (score 31):

I also struggled a few days fixing this issue. In my case, I restart the computer and enable the virtualization technology in BIOS. Then start up computer, open `VM Virtual Box`, choose a virtual device, go to `Settings`-`General`-`Basic`-`Version`, choose `ubuntu(64 bit)`, save the settings then start virtual device from genymotion, everything is ok now.

Answer (score 11):

Okay so I found a solution to `run an emulator of an Android device` via an alternative method.

First, run the emulator from Virtualbox UI. It should boot as in the question above. Let it finish booting until the home screen appears .
Then, run the same device from Genymotion UI.

And voila. 
Note that, if you have just created a device in Genymotion, you will need to run it from there the first time. Even if/when it fails, this is still necessary, otherwise it can't be started from VirtualBox interface. After that first run, the emulator will run from VirtualBox, as well, and the above procedure will work.
After this, you will have two windows open - VirtualBox device window with Android emulator running, which is where you will use the device; and Genymotion window with device controls. It is a crazy setup but it works!

Note also that the screen rotation won't work.

Comment: I have to say I don't understand most of what you are trying to say here. :( Which emulator should we run? What is the end result here? Can we still get an emulated Android device running through Genymotion (with proper screen scaling) or does it run just in VirtualBox? While I'm getting this error in Genymotion, I can still run the emulated device in VirtualBox. There is no decent screen resizing but using the Scale mode helps a bit.

Comment: Running the emulator from VirtualBox *first* is a great idea. Genymotion recognizes that the device is running and displays the shell. However, this worked for an emulator created with an older version of Genymotion, which had to be upgraded. After creating a new emulator, it can't run in either shells (VirtualBox or Genymotion). Awesome!

Comment: This is the right solution and the simplest one.

Answer (score 7):

I also had the same issue. First start your virtual box. Then in Setting go to General there you have to change the type of your OS to your current OS save it and it runs perfectly.

Comment: The OS setting in virtual box is supposed to be for the guest os not the host

Answer (score 6):

My VirtualBox Version:5.2.22, after those step ,solved my problem. Hope it helps you too.

Step 1: Find your emulator network adapter

[image]

Step 2: Open Global Tools

Step 3: change IP of your device then apply

[image]

Step 4: Click DHCP server tab

Step 5: Change Server Address and Address Bounds depending on your Wifi router then apply

Step 6: Start your device from Genymotion

[image]

Comment: I have tried almost every other fixes(from stack and other communities) and I was on the verge of giving up. But this answer helped me to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue. Setting->General->Basic and change version 32 bit to 64 bit. Then it worked well.

Comment: settings of what?

Comment: setting of your genymotion machine

Answer (score 1):

Just simply change the **Network mode** in the Configure virtual device.

If it's not work, log off the computer, logon again and run Genymotion Device first of all.

[image: Configure virtual device]

Answer (score 1):

It's simple!

1. Open Oracle VM Virtual
2. RIGHT-CLICK your phone -> settings -> General ->
3. Type: Choose your operating
4. Version: Windows version

DONE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: The OS setting in virtual box is supposed to be for the guest os not the host

Comment: The setting corresponds to the Guest Os and not host OS.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was reducing the number of processors from 4 to 2. My Mac Pro defaulted to 4 when I created the VM.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue, and fixed it by downloading a new virtual device from genymotion

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by enabling Virtualization (VTx) in my BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is by turning on Hardware Virtualization if in any case its already turned on / enable, just turn it off and turn it on back again. Then restart your PC.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and have tried a lot of solutions. In my case the problem was that my CPU does not support Virtualization Technology, which is required by most of Genymotion Devices, so it can't be solved.
The most recent Genymotion Virtual Device that works for me is Nexus 4 with Android 4.4.4 API 19.

Answer (score 0):

Please look in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21486549/2034822 which solved my problem. Hope it helps you too.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow this issue is related to my device's memory settings.
Here is what I ended up doing to solve this problematic case :

1. Open Virtual Box
2. Choose your device, then open Settings (either by clicking yellow gear icon in menu bar or by right click -> Settings
3. There should a warning about the device if it is using too much memory. If there is not don't worry about it.
4. Open System tab, change the Base memory to 1024 MB (anything below 1024 is fine)
5. Save Settings and go back to Genymotion, start your device again and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue on **Mac OS Sierra**. I simply **quit** ***VBoxNetDHCP*** and ran the Genymotion virtual device again - this time it ran smoothly. This is how you can try the same:

Open *Activity Monitor* (You can use *Spotlight Search* for this) -> Select the *CPU* tab -> in the search bar on the right enter *DHCP* -> in the results, if visible, select *VBoxNetDHCP* -> click on the cross button on the top left -> choose *Quit* -> Re-run your virtual device and it should work this time :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Genymotion Icon]

Click the Genymotion Icon and open the Genymotion Device Manager.  Click on Start.  One the device tries to start it will give you the error.  Close the error, and click on refresh on the Genymotion Device Manager and then Start again.  That solves the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

for this problem first check your machine has enabled Virtualization Technology in bios setting.

It generally goes disabled when you open your laptop or computer board and rewired hard disk state or take out CMOS battery for replacing or cleaning purpose.

In some Intel based board it comes disabled by default. And virtualization technology is needed when you  partition a computer to work as if it has several  computers, allowing systems to run many operating system(like in a virtual box, VMware) at the same time.

restart of computer> go to the bios setting(by pressing esc,f1,...f12 could be any according to the type of board)> then enabled virtualization technologies (by searching on a tab menus)> save and restart your machine> now you can change setting of your virtual device(not necessary) from right clicking on that device and go to the setting>general>basic>change the version to 64 bit.... and you are ready to go

Answer (score 0):

If those answers are not working 
go to windows features and uncheck **hyper-v**

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by unchecking "Enable EFI (special OSes only)" on virtualbox device settings -> system

Answer (score 0):

For me it is fixed by plugging in the power into my laptop. I guess when its just on battery, something goes wrong like CPUs going to sleep or something