# Genymotion: The virtual device got no IP address?

Tags: android, emulation, genymotion

Whenever I try to launch my virtual device in Genymotion, I receive an error stating that it has no ip address.  DHCP is enabled in VirtualBox and it all seems fine to my knowledge.  I tried disabling/enabling the network adapter too, no luck.  Also did a full re-install.  Not sure what else to do. I am open to suggestions.

System:
Windows 10 x64
Quad Core CPU 3.0 ghz
4 GB RAM

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After 2 days R&D I found solution.

#### Steps 1:

Go to **BIOS** settings -> Go to **System Configuration** -> **Enable** **Virtualization Technology** -> **Save and Exit** from **BIOS** settings.

#### Steps 2:

Open **Oracle VM VirtualBox** -> Select your **simulator** -> Go to **settings** of simulator -> Select **General** tab -> Select **Basic** sub tab -> Select your **OS type** -> Select your **Version of your OS** -> **Save and Exit**

#### Steps 3:

**Restart** your **Genymotion** and **Start Genymotion simulator**.

**Reference Screenshots:**

#### Steps 1:

[image]

#### Steps 2:

[image]

Hope this would help you.

Comment: The 2nd step incredibly works for me. But I still don't understand why... Why is an android image supposed to be configured as a Windows system?

Comment: Hiren Sir Rocked, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**Step1**
Ensure you have  Virtualization Technology enabled in your BIOS.

**Step 2**
Open Virtualbox and go to “File » Preferences” (CTRL+G), then head over “Network » Host-only adapters“,click the “minus” button. Confirm it, and try after restarting your PC.

**Step 3**
If above solution does not work for you delete virtual machine from Genymotion and re install the Virtual Machine by Clicking add button.

**Step 4**
Another trick is exit all  those programs which are using internet for example browser,skype,teamviewer etc. Then run genymotion and now launch your emulator. 
After successful launch of emulator you can launch any program.

Answer (score 3):

No one responded to Mac users, in my case it was much easier.

- Just turn-off the wi-fi and turn-on

... that's all. It recovers a new IP[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NZ38.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Check if your CPU has support for Virtualization Technology, and enable it in BIOS if it was disabled. This is required by most of Genymotion Virtual Devices, otherwise they will not work.
If this step is OK, maybe you will find your case there:

[Genymotion - The virtual device got no IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29008767/genymotion-the-virtual-device-got-no-ip-address/38058222)

[Not able to start Genymotion device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641423/not-able-to-start-genymotion-device)

Answer (score -1):

try to clear the cache in genymotion 
Setting -> Misc -> Clear cache.

[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUCim.png)

maybe it will solve the problem.