# Virtual device in Genymotion not getting started in windows 8.1

Tags: android, genymotion

On starting virtual device in Genymotion I am getting below error message.
[image]

Comment: start and restart VirtualBox.

Comment: @Chetan I tried but its not working , I am getting same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Below Link it could help you :

[Genymotion - The virtual device got no IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29008767/genymotion-the-virtual-device-got-no-ip-address)

(1).Open Oracle VM Virtual box

(2).Select the 
custom phone -> right click->settings->General->Basic

(3).Change the type to your current OS (4).Choose Version of the windows In My case: I'm using Windows 10 -so,I Chose other Windows(64 bit)

Comment: Thanks it opening emulator now but the problem is the screen is blank . I tried by running small hello world app but still I got blank screen.I am new to use Genymotion have you any idea regarding this..?

Comment: have you added setcontentView

Comment: Try to run other default app in your emulator.

Comment: yes I have added setContentView . The application is running on my android device and also in android studio emulator but not in Genymotion emulator.

Comment: have you restarted your  genymotion emulator.

Comment: Yes, I have restarted that also.