# Can't open a device in Genymotion

Tags: linux, ubuntu, genymotion, ubuntu-14.04

I'm having trouble when trying to open a device in Genymotion (in Ubuntu 14.04).

This is the bug that I'm getting.

[image: Unable to start the Genymotion virtual device. VirtualBox can't run the virtual device. Try to run the virtual device directly from VirtualBox to check for issues. Check the log files for more information.]

I tried to uninstall Genymotion and Virtualbox a few times but nothing helped.

Comment: As it says, check the log files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not able to start Genymotion device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641423/not-able-to-start-genymotion-device)

Answer (score 0):

I has the same problem with Genymotion 2.1.0 as there is a bug in Virtual Box 4.2.
I installed genymotion 2.2.0, which solved the problem.

Comment: Hi, I use Genymotion 2.2.0 and Virtualbox-4.3

Comment: this is already answered here check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922077/genymotion-unable-to-start-the-genymotion-virtual-device