# Genymotion emulator does not start

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, genymotion

I have installed genymotion software, oracle virtual box manager and the eclipse plug in . I have configured the settings as shown in various video tutorials

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YjHk1VtLk8c

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_W8cYZ5uiA

When i click the start button on the genymotion application the loading sign comes up but there is no output

the dialog box of initializing does not show up and the emulator does not start

how to fix this ?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922077/genymotion-unable-to-start-the-genymotion-virtual-device) which help you.

Answer (score 3):

I had a problems recently with Genymotion on OSX, but the real problem is on the filesystem. Because it is case-sensitive and the default it is case-insensitive. To resolve the problem i needed rename player.app to Player.app

Like this:

```
mv /Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/player.app /Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/Player.app
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check the logs for the particular emulator image in genymotion. It should give you a zip file of the emulator logs. Check each file to see the issue.

I had a similar problem in ubuntu, I checked the logs and it turned out that the issue was that ufw blocked access from the vm to the dhcp server. I added some ufw rules to allow access, and the emulator was able to run.