# Genymotion fails to boot - stuck on Starting Virtual Device

Tags: android, virtual-machine, genymotion

I am trying to boot a Genymotion Virtual Machine for any Android device, and primarily my issue was that the Ethernet adaptor used by the device was broken. I uninstalled and reinstalled this, enabling it. Now my virtual machine gets stuck on "Starting virtual device".

Logs say it gets stuck on:

```
2021-05-10T16:12:28+01:00 [Genymotion Player:11832] [warning] "Camera 192.168.198.102:24800 error: Connection timed out new attempt in 5000 ms"
2021-05-10T16:12:28+01:00 [Genymotion Player:11832] [warning] "Camera 192.168.198.102:24810 error: Connection timed out new attempt in 5000 ms"
2021-05-10T16:12:29+01:00 [Genymotion Player:11832] [emugl.geny.warning] writeFully: failed: Bad file descriptor
2021-05-10T16:12:29+01:00 [Genymotion Player:11832] [warning] Unable to send START OPENGL command
2021-05-10T16:12:51+01:00 [Genymotion Player:11832] [emugl.geny.warning] writeFully: failed: Bad file descriptor
2021-05-10T16:12:51+01:00 [Genymotion Player:11832] [warning] Unable to send START OPENGL command
2021-05-10T16:13:13+01:00 [Genymotion Player:11832] [emugl.geny.warning] writeFully: failed: Bad file descriptor
2021-05-10T16:13:13+01:00 [Genymotion Player:11832] [warning] Unable to send START OPENGL command
2021-05-10T16:13:15+01:00 [Genymotion Player:11832] [warning] "Camera 192.168.198.102:24810 error: Connection timed out new attempt in 5000 ms"
2021-05-10T16:13:15+01:00 [Genymotion Player:11832] [warning] "Camera 192.168.198.102:24800 error: Connection timed out new attempt in 5000 ms"
```

I cannot find anything anywhere about this issue or a fix for it. I am not sure what to do. I already have SVM enabled in my BIOS.

System specs:

Windows 10 Home x64 
 AMD Radeon RX 6700 XT 
 AMD Ryzen 5 5600X 
 16GB DDR4 3600 MHz

Comment: Updating the VirtualBox to 6.1.32 worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today , I'm facing same issue .. Solved by :

1. Uninstall Genymotion & Virtualbox
2. Try to update your PC drivers "All drivers , not only GPU Drivers" using  any solution like driver booster .
   after update your driver restart pc 2 times to double check your pc got new drivers was installed
3. reinstall Genymotion & virtualbox

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on mac, I resolved mine by turning off the wifi and then starting the device. Try turning off your wifi and also disabling LAN adapter from Network and Sharing centre

Answer (score 0):

Ref:https://docs.genymotion.com/desktop/latest/01_Get_started.html#hardware

You must not have enabled VT-x or AMD-V/SMV in your system from your boot menu.
Since you're using an AMD processor it will be the AMD-V/SMV.

Here's a link on how you can do that

https://www.qnap.com/en/how-to/faq/article/how-to-enable-intel-vtx-and-amd-svm

Edit 1:
Update your drivers at https://www.amd.com/en/support

Comment: Just updated my driver to the latest Optional driver instead of Recommended... the issue still persists.

Comment: this might be a helpful answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922077/genymotion-unable-to-start-the-genymotion-virtual-device

Comment: That doesn't help... those answers are over 5 years old, most of the things the answers describe aren't even part of VirtualBox anymore.